# Angular 4 - Component selector is not showing HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop

I need to drag and drop(HTML 5) component selector which should be converted to relevant HTML elements. But what i see it is component selector in HTML.

`<div><ang-textfield></ang-textfield></div>`

I am describing briefly -

I made two custom attribute directives to drag and drop fields.

```
<button md-raised-button type="button" draggable="true" dragTextField>Text Field</button>
```

Here `dragTextField` is a custom attribute directive to handle `dragstart` event.

My *dropzone* is -

```
<div id="selected-form-fields" dropFields>
  Drop fields
</div>
```

Here `dropFields` is another custom attribute directive to handle `drop` and `dragover` event.

Here are `@HostListener` events for handling drag and drop -

```
@Directive({ selector: '[dragTextField]' })
export class DragTextFieldDirective {

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

@HostListener('dragstart', ['$event']) ondragstart(event) {
    this.dragstart_handler(event);
}

private dragstart_handler(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "<ang-textfield></ang-textfield>");
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "<ang-textfield></ang-textfield>");
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", "<ang-textfield></ang-textfield>");
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/uri-list", "<ang-textfield></ang-textfield>");
    event.dropEffect = "copy";
}}
@Directive({ selector: '[dropFields]' })
export class DropFieldsDirective {

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) ondrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.drop_handler(event);
}

@HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) ondragover(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.drag_over_handler(event);
}

private drop_handler(event) {
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = data;
    console.log(div);
    event.target.appendChild(div);
    return false;
}

private drag_over_handler(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
}}
```

Drag and Drop work fine. Even i implemented `<ang-textfield>` component selector and added the selector to `app.module.ts` `declarations`

What i am expecting is -

```
private drop_handler(event) {
var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
console.log(div);
event.target.appendChild(div);
return false;}
```

`console.log(div);` would deliver HTML elements rather than `<ang-textfield>`